# How to extract elements from a list after a match?

Tags: tcl

I have a variable and a list as below.

```
set check a7
```

```
set element_list "a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10"
```

I want a list in which I have all elements after a7:

```
a8 a9 a10
```

How can I do this? The "element_list" is sorted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what should happen if the "check" element is not in the list. Because you indicated the list is sorted, I assume you will still want the elements that would be after the searched element.

```
set check a7
set element_list "a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10"
set last [lsearch -bisect -dictionary -exact $element_list $check]
puts [lreplace $element_list 0 $last]
```

The bisect option of lsearch will return the last index where the element is less than or equal to the pattern. Then lreplace can be used to remove everything up to and including that index. This works correctly even if "check" would be before the first element.

Comment: The `lsearch` manual page indicates that the -bisect option implies -sorted, but doesn't mention if the same is true for -exact. I can't imagine -bisect doing anything useful with -glob or -regexp matching, but I just added -exact to be on the safe side.

Comment: An alternative to the last line: `puts [lrange $element_list $last+1 end]`

Comment: Even though this is not perl, TIMTOWTDI. I've been led to believe that the M+N form for indexes is less than optimal, performance wise. And writing `[expr {$last + 1}]` is just too much work. That's why I opted for `lreplace` instead of `lrange`. But both will work.